# jQuery Mobile radio disable if not checked by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I am returning the results of a form back to the user upon submitting. This form includes fieldsets of radio buttons. The resulting view after POST returns their selection with a default checked state. How can I disable all radio buttons that are not checked?

To give code example:

```
<input id="1-4" name="section[1]" value="3" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<input id="1-5" name="section[1]" value="4" type="radio" />
```

So from this, I need jQuery (mobile) to disable all radio boxes, which is easy, but recognize the checked state and enable that particular one so that the proper markup in placed, or in this case removed, from the DOM.

All of this code is dynamically generated in the system. In an effort to reuse code as much as possible, it would be best to manipulate the DOM rather than writing code to further separate the form from the view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to `disable` the unchecked `radio` elements *and* remove them from the DOM? Or 'just' `disable` them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input:radio').prop('disabled', function(){ return !this.checked; });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ayB3d/).

Or:

```
$('input:radio').prop('disabled', function(){ return !this.defaultChecked; });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ayB3d/1/).

References:

- [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).